# can someone teach me how to use property file for a simple login application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

can someone help me with using property file for a sample login application? this helps in achieving me for another big automation.

I have given objects in objects.propreties

in main java class how shall i proceed with?

```
 package valuescompare;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class practice {

public static FileInputStream fis;
public static String propertyfilepath="E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\valuescompare\\src\\valuescompare\\object.properties";

public static String getProperty(String key) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    fis=new FileInputStream(propertyfilepath);
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    prop.load(fis);
    return prop.getProperty(key);
}
static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        public static void openBrowser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            //public  WebDriver driver;

             driver.get(getProperty("url"));
            //maximizes the window
             driver.manage().window().maximize();
             Wait(1000);

    }   

    public  static void login() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(getProperty("uidxpath"))).sendKeys(getProperty("uid"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(getProperty("pwdxpath"))).sendKeys(getProperty("pwd"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(getProperty("submit"))).click();
            Wait(5000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*practice prac=new practice();
        prac.openBrowser();
        prac.login(); */
        openBrowser();
        login();
    }
    public static void Wait(int time){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you create a 'config.properties' named file somewhat like this :

```
userName=admin
password=admin
```

and say you are using Java as your programming language, then you have to use it in this manner:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("Config.properties"));
String uName = properties.getProperty("userName");
String pwd = properties.getProperty("password");
```

Now you have got the values fetched from properties file, use it wherever required.

For more info you may refer this link: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: implementation and above properties code will be in the same class?

Comment: No the properties file is a different file whose name will be **'Config.properties'**. Here we are giving the path to properties file using `FileInputStream()`, If you are keeping it in the same package as your java class where you are using you can use it directly as mentioned. if it is in another package say 'xyz' you have to call it like : new `FileInputStream("xyz\\Config.property")`

Comment: # sign In
url="http://example.com/"
uidxpath=".//*[@id='LoginUsername"
uid="qa"
pwdxpath=".//*[@id='LoginPassword']"
pwd="welcome"
submit="html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/button"

Comment: public class practice {
public static  WebDriver driver;
public FileInputStream fis;
public String propertyfilepath="E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\valuescompare\\src\\valuescompare\\object.properties";
public String getProperty(String key) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
 fis=new FileInputStream(propertyfilepath);
 Properties prop=new Properties();
 prop.load(fis);
 return prop.getProperty(key);
}
public static void openBrowser() {
    driver.get("url");
   //maximizes the window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Wait(500);
}

Comment: public static void login(){
  
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(uidxpath)).sendKeys("uid");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginPassword']")).sendKeys("welcome");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/button")).click();
   Wait(5000);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
 public static void Wait(int time){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
}
}

Comment: No, since you have created a function `getProperty` to handle properties. Use it wherever you want to call properties. Ex: Use get(getProperty("url")) INSTEAD OF get("url"), xpath(getProperty("uidxpath")) INSTEAD OF xpath(uidxpath) and so on...

Comment: i have edited by qs, that is the main java class but throwing this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at valuescompare.practice.openBrowser(practice.java:26)
 at valuescompare.practice.main(practice.java:44)

Comment: i edited my ans, pls check that one worked for me, if there is any mistake pls let me know

Comment: Yes this looks fine. Earlier you were getting the issue since you declared the WebDriver but didn't initialize it. Also, Please accept my answer if it was of help.

Comment: thanks, im beginner in automation, need help in future also. can we have gtalk chat outside this?

Comment: I don't use Gtalk. You can drop me an email to pnp.prateek@gmail with your query. I'll try to reply over it as soon as possible.

Comment: I started with w3schools then guru99 and then mkyong.com. There are lot of tutorials available online. But if you are focusing on selenium, try to get a hold on collections and practice a lot.

Comment: oh ok collections, sure i will try with that. java also i am beginner. :(